# Secure Web Api to consumed by console Appplicatuion

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, windows-authentication, basic-authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created one Asp core web api which will be consumed by C# console application outside the organization. This console application is scheduled to run periodically . So hits on Web api will come when console application run.
Please assist How Can i secure my Web Api to malware hit or unauthentic access. I can't use AD authentication as I am unable to register client application in AAD(Azure active directory) Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking , there're lots ways to do that . For example , use a basic scheme authentication in which the client sends `username:password` with the base64-encoding . However . It's not that safe .

I suggest you use JWT token . The authentication of Jwt scheme is dead simple :

1. The client send a request to ask for a `JWT` token with `client_id` and `client_key` . (You might configure them in configuration file or database on server)
2. Tf the `client_id` and `client_key` matches , the Server send a response with a `JWT` access token , maybe an additional refresh token if you like ; otherwise , send a response with a `401`.
3. The client consumes webapi with a `Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}` header. The server will decrypt the `access_token` and hit the correct action if valid.

Here's a how-to in details:

1. Dummy class to hold information

To represent the `client_id` and `client_key` sent by your console , Let's create a dummy Dto class :

```
public class AskForTokenRequest
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientKey { get; set; }
}
```

When creating and validating Jwt token , we need information about issuer , audience , and secret keys . To hold these information , let's create another dummy class :

```
public class SecurityInfo {
    public static readonly string Issuer = "xxx";
    public static readonly string[] Audiences = new[] { "yyy" };
    public static readonly string SecretKey = "!@#$%^&*()&!!!@#$%^&*()&!!!@#$%^&*()&!!!@#$%^&*()&!!!@#$%^&*()&!";
}
```

2. Before we move on , let's create a `JwtTokenHelper` to generate token :

The `JwtTokenHelper` helps to validate `client_id` & `client_key` and generate `Jwt` Token .

```
public class JwtTokenHelper
{
    //private AppDbContext _dbContext { get; set; }

    //public JwtTokenHelper(AppDbContext dbContext) {
    //    this._dbContext = dbContext;
    //}

    public virtual bool ValidateClient(string clientId, string clientKey)
    {
        // check the client_id & clientKey with database , config file , or sth else 
        if (clientId == "your_console_client_id" && clientKey == "your_console_client_key")
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    /// construct a token
    public virtual JwtSecurityToken GenerateToken(string clientId, DateTime expiry, string audience)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(clientId, "jwt"));
        var token=new JwtSecurityToken
        (
            claims: identity.Claims,
            issuer: SecurityInfo.Issuer,
            audience: audience,
            expires: expiry,
            notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecurityInfo.SecretKey)),
                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256
            )
        );
        return token; 
    }


    public virtual string GenerateTokenString(string clientId, DateTime expiry,string audience)
    {
        // construct a jwt token
        var token = GenerateToken(clientId,expiry,audience);
        // convert the token to string
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }

}
```

3. Configure the server to enable JwtBearer authentication :

Add `JwtTokenHelper` to DI Container and Add authentication scheme of JwtBearer

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<JwtTokenHelper>();
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = SecurityInfo.Issuer,
                ValidAudiences = SecurityInfo.Audiences,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKeys = new List<SecurityKey> {
                    new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecurityInfo.SecretKey) )
                },
                ValidateLifetime = true, 
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60) 
            };
        });

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Don't forget to add `app.UseAuthentication();` in your `Configure()` method .

4. How to use:

Now , Create a controller to generate Jwt token

```
[Route("/api/token")]
public class TokenController : Controller
{
    private readonly JwtTokenHelper _tokenHelper;

    public TokenController(JwtTokenHelper tokenHelper) {
        this._tokenHelper = tokenHelper;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] AskForTokenRequest client)
    {
        if(! this._tokenHelper.ValidateClient(client.ClientId , client.ClientKey)) 
            return new StatusCodeResult(401);

        DateTime expiry = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60); // expires in 1 hour 
        var audience = "yyy";
        var access_token = this._tokenHelper.GenerateTokenString(client.ClientKey, expiry,audience);
        return new JsonResult(new { 
            access_token = access_token,
        });
    }
}
```

and protect you webapi with `[Authorize]` attribute :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult GetYourWebApiMethod(){
        return new ObjectResult(new {
            Username = User.Identity.Name
        });                
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Your explained solution. Here we are talking about basic authentication. We will ask consumer call our api two times. 1 for get token, 2 for get result . 

Can we think for different way of authentication ?

Comment: @NitinJain if you want to use the basic authentication scheme ,you can refer another answer of mine : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51979589/how-to-use-basic-authentication-in-my-application